# What is the difference between $remote_addr and $real_ip_remote_addr nginx variables

Tags: nginx

After reading the docs, its still unclear to me what the difference is between `$remote_addr` and `$real_ip_remote_addr` nginx variables.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `$real_ip_remote_addr` will contain the requesting IP address that directly interacts with the NGINX instance, as in *the connecting IP*.

So in case of requests are proxied to NGINX, e.g. from Varnish or Cloudflare, the `$real_ip_remote_addr` will be the IP of either Varnish instance (`127.0.0.1`, if configured on the same server) or a Cloudflare IP.

The `$remote_addr` will contain the actual visitor IP address, provided that you have configured `set_real_ip_from` appropriately.